# Считать множество JSON файлов в один DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Дано: 10к JSON файлов размером не более 100-120 Кб.
Необходимо: считать эти JSON файлы в единственный `DataFrame`. JSON файлы имеют структуру:

```
{
"cookieDisclaimerAgree" : true,

"data" : +{ ... },
"isFollowed" : false,
"paywall" : +{ ... },
"showErrorFeedbackButton" : true,
"showFollowButton" : true,
"showFollowReminder" : false,
"showNps" : false,
"showRequestDocsButton" : false,
"showTaxRiskButton" : false
}
```

Нужно извлечь данные из каждого ключа "data" в отдельную строку.

1. Как считать JSON в DataFrame?
2. Как автоматизировать этот процесс для 10000 JSON файлов в папке?

Comment: В Апач.Спарк не умею, если что

Comment: Можете указать список из 2-3 записей, которые включают вложенные данные `data` и `paywall` и привести пример того что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [338]: data = [
     ...: {
     ...: "cookieDisclaimerAgree" : True,
     ...: "data" : {"id": 111, "name":"name1"},
     ...: "isFollowed" : False,
     ...: "showErrorFeedbackButton" : True,
     ...: "showFollowButton" : True,
     ...: "showFollowReminder" : False,
     ...: "showNps" : False,
     ...: "showRequestDocsButton" : False,
     ...: "showTaxRiskButton" : False
     ...: },
     ...: {
     ...: "cookieDisclaimerAgree" : True,
     ...: "data" : {"id": 112, "name":"name2"},
     ...: "isFollowed" : False,
     ...: "showErrorFeedbackButton" : True,
     ...: "showFollowButton" : True,
     ...: "showFollowReminder" : False,
     ...: "showNps" : False,
     ...: "showRequestDocsButton" : False,
     ...: "showTaxRiskButton" : False
     ...: }]

In [339]: df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)

In [340]: df
Out[340]:
   cookieDisclaimerAgree  data.id data.name  isFollowed        ...          showFollowReminder  showNps  showRequestDocsButton  showTaxRiskButton
0                   True      111     name1       False        ...                       False    False                  False              False
1                   True      112     name2       False        ...                       False    False                  False              False

[2 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Именно Вас и ждал)